# Laravel Eloquent, where с несколькими вариациями значения столбца?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Использую Laravel Eloquent отдельно от Laravel. Как я могу за один запрос получить данные с несколькими значениями определенного столбца?
Пример:
Есть таблица комментариев пользователей и мне необходимо получить только комментарии пользователя со статусом "active" от пользователей с ID 2 и 6, подразумеваю, что запрос должен быть вида:

```
->where('status',  '=' , 'active')
->orWhere('uid',  '=', '2')
->orWhere('uid',  '=', '6')
->get()
```

Но он не срабатывает, я либо получаю все записи со статусом active, либо не получаю никакие записи.

Answer (score 0):

Решение нашлось с помощью оператора 'whereIn('uid', [2, 6])' вместо 'orWhere()'

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses